# SQL SELECT statement that displays number of wins/losses based off a value ("win" or "loss")

Tags: mysql, sql, select

A Tenis database I'm working with contains rows as matches. The row has the player name and a condition (win or loss). I need to display a table with ALL the players showing the player name, total games, number of wins, number of losses and win percentage.

I haven't figured out how to properly set up the SELECT statement to perform what I need. Somewhere to start would be:

`SELECT player, COUNT(player) FROM tenis_table GROUP BY player`

Grouping by player shows every unique player name, and COUNT(player) gives me the total games played. But how do I properly create an SQL SELECT statement that also gives me a column with the number of wins, losses and win percentage based off a condition that is either "win" or "loss"?

Comment: Can you share the table's structure please?

Comment: Agreed with above.  Need to understand better the attributes of the tenis_table which you are pulling from.

If the win/loss percentage is not contained as a value in your data base, you will need to create a user defined function which will divide the wins by total games for each row (player name,)

Comment: The thing is, those are the only relevant columns: player (which is a player name) and condition (which is either "win" or "loss"). There's a date, opponent name, and some irrelevant stats as well.

Comment: @Holmes You're right. I could definitely work on the win percentage outside the SQL SELECT if I had the number of wins and losses. Sorry for asking for that one as well, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realistically, you should only be asking for player, TotalGames, and Wins.  Everything else should be done in your code, but here it is in case you absolutely want to stray from good design:

```
SELECT player, 
  COUNT(*) AS TotalGames,
  SUM(CASE WHEN condition='win' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wins,
  COUNT(*)-SUM(CASE WHEN condition='win' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Losses,
--  SUM(CASE WHEN condition='loss' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Losses,
  SUM(CASE WHEN condition='win' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100/COUNT(*) AS WinPercentage
FROM tenis_table
GROUP BY player
```

Also, COUNT(player) will give you the total number of records in the group, only if `player` is not null.  COUNT(*) I believe is slightly faster because it does not have to check if each record's `player` is null or not, so I've switched to that.

Comment: total - wins <> losses.  In many games you can have ties.  You should calculate losses the same way that you calculate wins.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I put that as a commented out line, but he did specify that the condition was either 'win' or 'loss', not 'win' or 'loss' or 'tie', so in this case, losses=total-wins.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Hey man, thanks for this. It always feels nice to learn something new. I'm doing losses and win percentage on the code instead. Oh and "condition" is a reserved word (it indeed was the name inside the table), I'm gonna have to change that column. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest way to write this code in MySQL is:

```
SELECT player, 
       COUNT(*) AS TotalGames,
       SUM(condition = 'win' ) AS NumWins,
       SUM(condition = 'lose') AS NumLosses,
       AVG(condition = 'win') AS WinPercentage
FROM tenis_table
GROUP BY player;
```

This uses a MySQL extension of treating boolean expressions as numbers (I happen to like this extension; `case` is also perfectly acceptable).  It simplifies the logic and uses `AVG()` for the computation of percentage.

I'm mostly answering because I disagree with Robert's first sentence:  the database is a fine place to do all the calculations.

Comment: And doing calculations in the database is a violation of separation of concerns, breaks [2NF database rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form), forces a transfer of useless data from database to client, and pushes doing calculations to the database server which in most cases would be better off being done on the client especially when there are multiple clients and only 1 database server.  All that stuff should be pushed to either the business layer (Losses), or to the presentation layer (WinPercentage).

Comment: @RobertMcKee . . . You clearly do not understand databases.  "Normal form" refers to the structure of data inside the database, not to how it is accessed.

Comment: It refers to the structure of data in general.  What would you call what you are getting from the database if not data?  If you think that data integrity is only important within the database that's fine, but I prefer to have my data integrity good all the way up the chain until it's actually consumed.  The same basic principles that are applied to databases holds true to any data source whether it be in an RDBMS, a collection, or even an XML file.  Duplicating redundant data when it's not needed just wastes space, compute time, introduces complexity, and opportunity for corruption.

Comment: `SUM(condition)` is a nicety of MySQL, and does make the query simpler, however, `CASE WHEN...` makes the query cross-database compatible, and will work unmodified in MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc and doesn't depend on the assumption that true=1 instead of true=-1 when converted to an int/float if there is an implicit cast available.

Comment: @spencer7593 Losses and WinPercentage in the database wasn't the correct place to do it. Both of those are redundant pieces of calculated data that aren't necessary given that you are already returning TotalGames and Wins. `Losses=TotalGames-Wins`, and `WinPercentage=Wins*100/TotalGames`.  There is no benefit to having the database server calculate those over having the clients calculate those, while there are many drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT player, 
  COUNT(*) AS TotalGames,
  SUM(CASE WHEN condition='win' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wins,
  SUM(CASE WHEN condition='loss' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Losses,
  SUM(CASE WHEN condition='win' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100/COUNT(*) AS WinPercentage
FROM tenis_table
GROUP BY player
```